# (How) Can I re-use an external USB hard drive after I DBAN it?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, wipe

Does anyone have experience with letting [Darik's Boot and Nuke](http://www.dban.org/) loose on an external USB hard disk, and then setting up that disk again for normal use?

I want to completely wipe my Toshiba px1220e-1g25, and then use it again.

Notes:

- The reason that I want to wipe the entire disk is that it contains a CDFS partition. I have tried approx. 20 programs which all fail to wipe or remove that partition.
- This question is not identical to [Started DBAN on an external by accident - can I get my data back?](https://superuser.com/questions/560767/started-dban-on-an-external-by-accident-can-i-get-my-data-back) where the OP wants to recover data after an accidental DBAN. I don't care about the data.

FWIW I'm using Windows 7

Comment: If you've tried to remove the partition 20 different ways and failed, this is probably a good sign of a hardware problem.  Can I assume you tried `diskpart` and `clean` on the drive?

Comment: @Jason your assumption about me having tried diskpart is correct, the one about a hardware problem is incorrect. What is 'clean'? http://superuser.com/questions/703273/how-can-i-repartition-and-format-toshiba-usb-2-0-ext-hdd-usb-device-containing I stopped documentation more software there.

Comment: Looking at your old question: you selected the disk, ran `clean`, it said it succeeded, but there was still the CDFS partition on there?  That's wacky.  Can you try again, make sure you've selected the disk (**not** the volume), then run `clean all`.  This one could take a few hours to finish.  It's basically the same as DBAN without the random pattern.

Comment: Nevermind... `clean all` or DBAN isn't going to help here.  I've answered your old question instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Disk Management](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-format-hard-disk-partition#create-format-hard-disk-partition=windows-7) after running DBAN,

Start > Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Storage > Disk Management.  Click the unallocated space and create a new volume.

Comment: Excuse me for asking for confimation, but is that 'from experience, having done this with a nuked external HD' or 'should work'? See the first phrase of my question.

Comment: Yes, from experience.